# Не могу правильно составить запрос hasAndBelongsToMany (многие ко многим) в CakePHP 2.x

Tags: php, framework, cakephp

Нужно сделать такой запрос

```
SELECT goods.* 
FROM goods, sections, sections_goods
where
sections_goods.good_id = goods.code
and sections_goods.section_id = sections.id 
and sections.id = 278 
limit 20;
```

Сделал по [CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html):

```
class Good extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Section' => array(
            'className'  => 'Section',
            'joinTable'  => 'sections_goods',
            'foreignKey' => 'good_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'section_id',
            'unique' => true
        ),
        'Group' => array(
            'className'  => 'Group',
            'joinTable'  => 'groups_goods',
            'foreignKey' => 'good_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
            'unique' => true
        ));
public function getRecomendedSection($section, $good){
        $recomended = $this->Good->find('all', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                    'Section.section_id' => $good['currentSection']['id']//id =278
                ),
                'fields'    => 'Good.*',
                'limit'     => 20-count($recomend)
       ));

}
```

}

Ошибка: `Error: Call to a member function find() on null`

Answer (score 1):

Сделал следующим способом:

```
class Good extends AppModel {
public function getRecomendedSection($section, $good){    
$recomended = $this->find('all', array(
                        'joins'     => array(
                            array(
                                'table' => 'sections_goods',
                                'alias' => 'SectionGood',
                                'type' => 'INNER',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'SectionGood.good_id = Good.code'
                                )
                            )
                        ),
                        'conditions' => array(
                            'SectionGood.section_id =' => $good['currentSection']['id']
                        ),
                        'recursive' => -1,
                        'fields'    => array('Good.*', 'SectionGood.*'),
                        'limit'     => 20-count($recomend)
                    ));
}
}
```